# No muestra las alertas correspondientes (Js, PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, login

se me ha presentado un problema con las alertas, y es que no me aparecen como deberían, este es mi JS:

```js
$("#frmAcceso").on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    logina=$("#logina").val();
    clavea=$("#clavea").val();

    if ((logina!="") && (clavea !=""))
    {

    $.post("../ajax/usuario.php?op=verificar",
        {"logina":logina, "clavea":clavea},
        function(data)
        {
            alert(data.length);
            alert(data);

            if (data)
           
            {
                Swal.fire({
                     type: 'success',
                     title: ':D',
                     text: 'You won :D'
                    })  
                $(location).attr("href","escritorio.php");

            }

            else if (data == ""|| data == null)

            {

            Swal.fire({
                     type: 'error',
                     title: ':(',
                     text: 'You commit a mistake :'

                     
        
                    })       
            }  
            return false; 
        });
}
else
    {
        $("#logina").focus();
        Swal.fire({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'You need to complete all the fields', 
        
    })       
    }
})
```

Y éste es el método PHP:

```php
case 'verificar':
    //validar si el usuario tiene acceso al sistema
    $logina=$_POST['logina'];
    $clavea=$_POST['clavea'];

    //Hash SHA256 en la contraseña
    $clavehash=hash("SHA256", $clavea);

    $rspta=$usuario->verificar($logina, $clavehash);

    $fetch=$rspta->fetch_object();
    if (isset($fetch)) {
        # Declaramos la variables de sesion
        $_SESSION['idusuario']=$fetch->idusuario;
        $_SESSION['nombre']=$fetch->nombre;
        $_SESSION['imagen']=$fetch->imagen;
        $_SESSION['login']=$fetch->login;

        //obtenemos los permisos
        $marcados=$usuario->listarmarcados($fetch->idusuario);

        //declaramos el array para almacenar todos los permisos
        $valores=array();

        //almacenamos los permisos marcados en al array
        while ($per = $marcados->fetch_object()) {
            array_push($valores, $per->idpermiso);
        }

        //determinamos lo accesos al usuario
        in_array(1, $valores)?$_SESSION['escritorio']=1:$_SESSION['escritorio']=0;
        in_array(2, $valores)?$_SESSION['almacen']=1:$_SESSION['almacen']=0;
        in_array(3, $valores)?$_SESSION['compras']=1:$_SESSION['compras']=0;
        in_array(4, $valores)?$_SESSION['ventas']=1:$_SESSION['ventas']=0;
        in_array(5, $valores)?$_SESSION['acceso']=1:$_SESSION['acceso']=0;
        in_array(6, $valores)?$_SESSION['consultac']=1:$_SESSION['consultac']=0;
        in_array(7, $valores)?$_SESSION['consultav']=1:$_SESSION['consultav']=0;

    }
    echo json_encode($fetch);


    break;
```

Y la función busca verificar que el usuario esté registrado en la página:

```php
public function verificar($login,$clave){

    $sql="SELECT idusuario,nombre,tipo_documento,num_documento,telefono,email,cargo,imagen,login FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' AND clave='$clave' AND condicion='1'";
     return ejecutarConsulta($sql);

}
```

Entonces el problema es que al dejar los dos campos vacíos de mi login obtengo la alerta que tengo que completar ambos campos, al tener uno vacío es igual, pero al rellenar ambos campos con datos falsos obtengo la alerta con un "null" y luego la alerta que yo asigné y cuando ingreso los datos correctos me imprime en una alerta esos datos y luego me deja acceder a mi página. ¿Qué puedo cambiar para que ya no tenga la alerta "null" y salga la alerta "you commit a mistake" y también que al ingresar los datos correctos no tenga una alerta que me muestre los datos que ingresé?

Comment: no puedes hacer: else(data == ""|| data == null), debería ser: else if(data == ""|| data == null)

Comment: No entiendo cuál de todas las alertas no debería aparecer.

Comment: Las alerta donde al ingresar datos erroneos obtengo un "null" en vez de la otra que dice "you commit a mistake" y al ingresar datos correctos me imprima en una etiqueta los datos que ingresé y no me sale la alerta que dice "you won"

Comment: Lo que dice @ChristianCarrillo es correcto, tenés un `else (...)` en JS. Un `else` no puede ir acompañado de una condición. Para eso tenés que usar `else if ()`.